# Scrolling Scene in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a sprite which moves across the screen.so i want to switch between the scenes.how can i do that.i am not interested in using Tile Map.I want just like angry birds scene scrolling.

Any Idea,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what your asking you could just add everything to a cclayer and have everything as a child of it and move the full layer left or right to scroll

Answer (score 0):

As glogic says, create a CCLayer and then add a CCSprite to it with an image much larger than the screen size.

Now in your touch handling code, do something like this...

*OnTouchBegin* - store position of the touch

*OnTouchMoved* - calculate distance from stored position where touch started and move the whole layer by that much.

*OnTouchEnd* - If your sprite has move too far and you have gone off the edge of the sprite, slide it back to the edge